# Snow Leopard login box – mouse click required?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, login-screen

I manage several Mac labs at a school, and I noticed something a little odd in one lab after recently reimaging the Macs.

Although there is a flashing cursor in the username field of the login box, users can't type anything in it, *unless* they click the username box first with a mouse.  Then they can type their usernames, passwords and login.

All my other Macs allow users to simply start typing their usernames – no click required. It's not exactly a huge annoyance, but I do get calls to the lab from students who think the keyboard must be broken, so I'd like to fix it.

Any Mac gurus have any idea why the login box would require a mouse click before being able to type?

Comment: Can you see any differences in the *System Preferences* for *Keyboard* between the machines where it works and the ones where it doesn't?

Comment: I just compared a mac that requires a mouse click to the macs in two different labs that don't have the issue, and the keyboard settings in system preferences are identical on all.